# In Go, how do you profile transitive init() cpu usage?

Tags: testing, go, initialization, profiling

I'm working on a project with a very large monorepo. When I run tests, the tests do not take very long to run the actual test case, but there is a lot of setup time before running the test.

I've tried `go test -i` not seeing much of a difference. I think that would suggest that the time is not a compilation time issue, so my next step is to profile everything that happens before running the test case.

There are many transitive dependencies and I would prefer to not manually look through the graph adding printlns to get the timings. Are there any tools to profile all the transitive initialization that happens in Go before running a test?

Comment: The Go toolchain tool for this would be [pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/). Requests for third-party tools are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: The tested package still needs to be compiled every time. You can use the `-x` flag to see all build steps if you want to see all compilation steps.

Comment: Adrian, wouldn't pprof end up profiling after initializations have all run, if that is my issue, I'd like to know how much time is spend in those.
JimB, that flag is helpful, I can see it's spending a good amount of that time compiling now. I may just have too many transitive dependencies to have a quick build.

Comment: @myyk: go1.10 has a new build cache system which may speed things up considerably. You can try the RCs right now if you want.